# Using docker behind a proxy on an EC2 instance

Tags: proxy, amazon-ec2, docker

I'm trying to run docker inside a EC2 VM instance. The instance is behind a http proxy. 
As far as I can tell the docker install went okay.

Here is the instance information

```
Linux ip-X-X-X-X 3.8.0-31-generic #46~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 11 18:21:16 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The docker version I've is

```
Docker version 0.6.3, build b0a49a3
```

When I try to run a simple docker command it hangs for a long time.

```
$sudo docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
Unable to find image 'ubuntu' (tag: latest) locally
Pulling repository ubuntu
```

I've a feeling that this has something to do with my HTTP proxy settings.

I tried setting proxy in different ways.

For example based on [this](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/813) I tried but it still doesn't work.

```
$sudo HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.xyz.com:8080 docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
Unable to find image 'ubuntu' (tag: latest) locally
Pulling repository ubuntu
```

Any idea what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be running the Docker daemon with your HTTP_PROXY environment variable, since the pulling of images happens through the daemon.  If you're on Ubuntu, this can be accomplished by modifying `/etc/init/docker.conf`.

Update:

We also correctly support `/etc/default/docker` now, so the best way to accomplish this now (on Ubuntu and Debian) is via `export http_proxy=...` inside `/etc/default/docker`.

Comment: can you please share more info how to add the proxy settings inf the docker.conf file? I've tried to add https_proxy=http://proxy:port /usr/bin/docker -d, but it doesn't work. I still get connection timeout.

Answer (score 3):

On Amazon Linux, append proxy variables in `/etc/sysconfig/docker`

```
export no_proxy='localhost,127.0.0.0/8'
export NO_PROXY='localhost,127.0.0.0/8'
export http_proxy=http://<YOUR_PROXY>:<PROXY_PORT>/
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://<YOUR_PROXY>:<PROXY_PORT>/
export https_proxy=http://<YOUR_PROXY>:<PROXY_PORT>/
export HTTP_PROXY=http://<YOUR_PROXY>:<PROXY_PORT>/
```

and then restart docker daemon
`service docker restart`

Answer (score 0):

Something to add to tianon's answer is after modifying the config file don't forget to restart the docker daemon:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

to apply the proxy.