# Network calls fail during image build on corporate network

Tags: dns, docker

I'm having a problem building Docker images on my corporate network. I'm just getting started with Docker, so I have the following Dockerfile for a hello-world type app:

```
# DOCKER-VERSION 0.3.4
FROM    centos:6.4
# Enable EPEL for Node.js
RUN     rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
# Install Node.js and npm
RUN     yum install -y npm
# Bundle app source
ADD . /src
# Install app dependencies
RUN cd /src; npm install
EXPOSE  8080
CMD ["node", "/src/index.js"]
```

This works fine when I build it on my laptop at home, on my own wireless network. It pulls down the requisite dependencies and builds the image correctly.

However, when I'm on my corporate network at work, this same docker build fails when trying to pull down the RPM from download.fedoraproject.org, with this error message:

> Step 2 : RUN     rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
>    ---> Running in e0c26afe9ed5
>   curl: (5) Couldn't resolve proxy 'some.proxy.address'
>   error: skipping http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm - transfer failed

On my corporate network, I can access that URL just fine from my laptop. But once Docker is trying to build the container, all of a sudden it can't resolve at all. This behavior is the same for a variety of external resources (apt-get, etc.): They all can resolve just fine on my laptop on the corporate network, but Docker can't resolve them.

I don't have the network know-how to figure out what's going on here. Does anyone know why this strange behaviour would be occurring when building Docker containers?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210563/using-docker-behind-a-proxy-on-an-ec2-instance it might also solve your issue

Comment: same problem occured to me. I had forgotten to run `apt-get update`.

Comment: These can be symptoms of "Docker does not pickup DNS information from Cisco AnyConnect"
https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-does-not-pickup-dns-information-from-cisco-anyconnect/16702

Comment: similar issue at home with ADSL connection. At my office, it works

Answer (score 98, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue. On Ubuntu, Docker sets the DNS servers for container to Google's servers at 8.8.8.x. As I understand it, this is a workaround on Ubuntu due to the fact that Ubuntu sets /etc/resolv.conf to be 127.0.0.1.

Those Google servers weren't accessible from behind our firewall, which is why we couldn't resolve any URLs.

The fix is to tell Docker which DNS servers to use. This fix depends on how you installed Docker:

### Ubuntu Package

If you have the Ubuntu package installed, edit /etc/default/docker and add the following line:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns <your_dns_server_1> --dns <your_dns_server_2>"
```

You can add as many DNS servers as you want to this config. Once you've edited this file you'll want to restart your Docker service:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

### Binaries

If you've installed Docker via the binaries method (i.e. no package), then you set the DNS servers when you start the Docker daemon:

```
sudo docker -d -D --dns <your_dns_server_1> --dns <your_dns_server_2> &
```

Comment: what about using the 'docker build' command with Dockfiles...it doesn't look like it works in those circumstances:
docker --dns=209.18.47.61 build . 2>&1 | tee ./output.txt

Comment: yeah this should work with docker build. docker build doesn't have a --dns flag on the command itself, but if you set it on the daemon like this then it will apply when using docker build

Comment: Thank you for this solution.  At my side the problem was, that docker apparently needs IPv4 to be available and enabled.  WTF?  Learn:  IPv4 is dead.  Software being IPv4 only is seriously broken.

Comment: I had already done this step and started getting the errors again. Restarting the service fixed it again.

Comment: I am having this issue with docker 1.7 although I have tried to run it either with `--dns` option or putting the config in `/etc/default/docker`

Comment: In my case I needed to set the --dns option when starting the docker daemon, but using the nameservers from the network did not work. Instead forcing it to use google's nameservers worked, i.e. 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.  This was docker 1.8.2 running on Centos7 trying to build a container based on Centos6.

Comment: @Quasaur this does not work for `docker build` see [luk's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42332682/4233593) to fix that with `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

Comment: Huh finally!! I added DNS from ubuntu dekstop network settings -> wired and there is DNS . I used it and works ;O

Answer (score 71):

I advise changing the DNS settings of the Docker daemon. You can set the default options for the docker daemon by creating a daemon configuration file at **/etc/docker/daemon.json**. Set DNS server according to your host machine, e.g. my DNS server is 10.0.0.2:

```
{"dns": ["10.0.0.2", "8.8.8.8"] }
```

Then you need just restart docker service:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Step-by-step explanation is available here [Fix Docker's networking DNS config](https://robinwinslow.uk/2016/06/23/fix-docker-networking-dns/)

Answer (score 21):

The following steps works for me ( for both docker build and docker run command). My linux version is Ubuntu 14.04.

- Identify DNS using following command.

  ```
  nm-tool | grep DNS
  ```

This result ***DNS:192.168.1.1*** in my case

- Create entry in /etc/default/docker.io. My current entry looks like this

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4 --dns 192.168.1.1"
```

- Restart docker service

```
 sudo service docker.io restart
```

Comment: The CentOS equivalent is the `/etc/sysconfig/docker` file, to which I was able to add the `DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8"` line and solve my problem.

Comment: OpenSuSE too has the `/etc/sysconfig/docker` file.

Answer (score 11):

For any Linux distribution working with SystemD (Ubuntu 16, RHEL 7...), the path will be displayed with the following command:

```
$ systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-06-29 08:10:33 PDT; 2min 34s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 1169 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 19
   Memory: 85.0M
      CPU: 1.779s
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           ├─1169 /usr/bin/dockerd --dns 172.18.20.11 --dns 172.20.100.15 --dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4 -H fd://
           └─1232 docker-containerd -l unix:///var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock --shim docker-containerd-shim --met
```

The path would be `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`. Add the `DOCKER_OPTS` values, which can have any of the `--dns`, in the line where the daemon is started.

```
cat /lib/systemd/system/docker.service | grep dns 
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --dns 172.18.20.11 --dns 172.20.100.15 --dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4  -H fd://
```

Comment: Thank you! After editing `docker.service` I had to stop the docker service with `sudo service docker stop` and then `systemctl daemon-reload` and finally `sudo service docker start`

Comment: You are better off adding a unit file in `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d` with the modified configuration (which systemd helpfully merges/overrides the system config) rather than changing the system version. The latter will be lost on upgrades.

Answer (score 9):

Docker (at least >=1.13, probably earlier) on Mac and Windows allow you configure the DNS in Preferences -> Daemon -> Advanced:

The following config sets two corporate DNS servers (use your own values here) with fallback to Google public DNS servers.

[image: Docker Daemon Adv Config]

Comment: Thanks Jason--if this doesn't work, see my later answer for the newer way to set DNS at the UI.

Answer (score 9):

Specify your DNS to the Docker daemon.

First of all get your DNS address

```
$ nmcli dev show | grep 'IP4.DNS'
IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.0.0.2
```

Test if the problem is really with the DNS by launching a docker container forcing this new DNS

```
$ docker run --dns 10.0.0.2 <image_name> <command_name>
```

If this solves the problem, you can apply this fix for all the docker daemons in the following way

Edit or create a file **/etc/docker/daemon.json**

Add the following line to this file

```
{
"dns": ["10.0.0.2", "8.8.8.8"]
}
```

Restart docker

```
$ sudo service docker restart
```

A very nice guide for doing ALL this process can be found here.

https://development.robinwinslow.uk/2016/06/23/fix-docker-networking-dns/

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Comment: if you installed by snap `daemon.json` will be at `/var/snap/docker/<id>/config/daemon.json`

Answer (score 3):

**Solution without restarting Docker service**

It is possible to modify the DNS settings for a single Docker image without affecting other `docker build` calls (and without restarting the Docker service) by overriding the `resolv.conf` at build time:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN echo "nameserver 123.123.123.123" > /etc/resolv.conf && apt update
```

Replace the IP `123.123.123.123` with the one which is used within your corporate network (use `nmcli dev show | grep 'IP4.DNS'` to get the currently used DNS server).

*Downsides:*

- This does not affect any other line from the Dockerfile. Hence, you have to prefix every line with the fix, if it depends on DNS resolution

Comment: No longer works, as /etc/resolv.conf was made read-only by Docker

Comment: Thanks for your comment, do you know in which version this change did happen?

Answer (score 1):

On my Ubuntu 16.04 machine, sometimes, Google's DNS do not work for building Docker images.

```
cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{"dns": [""8.8.8.8"] }
```

I have to manually find out my Service Providers DNS using the following command

```
nmcli device show <interfacename> | grep IP4.DNS

125.22.47.102
```

and add it to my `daemon.json` as show below

```
cat /etc/docker/daemon.json 

{"dns": ["125.22.47.102","8.8.8.8"] }

 restart docker

sudo service docker restart
```

(PS nm-tool is deprecated from Ubuntu 15.04)

Answer (score 0):

**Updated info September 2021**

Inspired by Jason's answer; setting DNS server in the JSON didn't work for me in the current version, but there's now another place to set it:

[image]

When you turn on the toggle, the 8.8.8.8 is already there, so I just left it and it works well enough for me in my dev environment. I didn't research it but if wanted, there may be a way to add a list, perhaps separated by commas/semicolons/spaces etc.

Comment: My Docker Desktop on Windows (v4.12.0) doesn't have that DNS option. It only has the subnet.