# Docker Ubuntu 16 on a Ubuntu 14 machine : no Internet connection

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I run a Ubuntu docker on my machine but when i type the `apt-get update` command, it says :

```
root@50e964833537:/# apt-get update
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done        
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried several "solutions" I found but still it doesn't work. 
I don't have access to any command in the docker because I can't update. I suppose because my Docker doesn't have access to Internet. How can I fix this ?

Comment: Is your host ubuntu 14 connected to the internet + is it able to resolve hostnames (dns)

Comment: Most probably your routes are wrong. Run `sudo route -n` and post the output. You can also run `ping 8.8.8.8` to ensure it's not a DNS issue.

Comment: I'm on a corporate network, it seems it's a DNS resolving problem. @Willian Paixao, I can't run any command in the docker it says "command not found".

Comment: Regarding the corporate network, that's a valuable information. There might have a transparent Proxy, which blocks unauthenticated requests. Regarding the command not found, that's really strange, try remove and pull the image again.

Comment: I followed these steps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151129/docker-network-calls-fail-during-image-build-on-corporate-network

It still doesn't work.

Comment: what is the output of `nm-tool | grep DNS`

Comment: If your server runs systemd it doesn't look at /etc/default/docker. Look at https://robinwinslow.uk/2016/06/23/fix-docker-networking-dns/ and at https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/ (this explains also how you can set HTTP_PROXY if your corporate network is behind a proxy.

Comment: I told you already : "nm-tool: command not found" This is why I need to do a apt-get update

Comment: I changed the DNS IP adress to the one I have on my machine, it worked well :
more /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 127.0.1.1 (on the docker)

Comment: and on your host, not inside your docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION :**

I'm in a corporate network so I had to change the DNS ip adresses by follow these steps :

On the Host Machine :

- `nm-tool | grep DNS` It will output the DNS servers
- `sudo nano /etc/default/docker` and change the following line with DNS you got in the first step:

  - `DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 'your_dns_server_1' --dns 'your_dns_server_2'"`
- Restart docker : `sudo service docker restart`

Answer (score 0):

For me it was our Internal VPN causing the issue. You should try turning it off once just to be sure.

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/1130898/no-internet-connection-inside-docker-containers) solution will work for you in this case.

> pkill docker;
>   iptables -t nat -F;
>   ifconfig docker0 down;
>   brctl delbr docker0