# Temporary failure in name resolution [Errno -3] with Docker

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker, pip, ubuntu-16.04

I'm following the [docker tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) and am on the part where I have to build the app using:

```
docker build -t friendlyhello .
```

It reaches up to step 4, where after a pause I get this error:

```
Step 4/7 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 7f4635a7510a
Collecting Flask (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))

Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after 
connection broken by
'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection 
object at 0x7fe3984d9b10>: Failed to establish a new connection: 
[Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/flask/
```

I'm not quite sure what this error means and how I can go about solving it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The error means pip had failed to resolve DNS name. First, check if networking works in Docker. Run `docker -it --rm python:2.7-slim /bin/bash` and then try running `ping pypi.python.org` and `ping -n 8.8.8.8`. Exit with ctrl-D or `exit`. If ping fails (post the results), then you have a problem with networking or DNS (update your question with OS details and Docker version). If it works, then, well, I suppose, you've ran into some bug with either Docker or pip - try adding `--verbose` so the command will be `RUN pip install --verbose -r requirements.txt`, maybe it'll provide something useful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The ping did indeed work fine, however the first command you mentioned, just gave me the error: unknown shorthand for i in '-it'.
When running with `--verbose` I get the following:

`Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/flask/
  Looking up "https://pypi.python.org/simple/flask/" in the cache
  No cache entry available`

Comment: The first command @drdaeman mentioned fails because it lacks the run command. Use this instead: `docker run -it --rm python:2.7-slim /bin/bash`

Comment: Did you suspend your computer in the before building the container?
On my laptop, docker deamon always stops name resolution after suspending. When I wake up the laptop again I always need to restart the deamon to get it back to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Network calls fail during image build on corporate network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151129/network-calls-fail-during-image-build-on-corporate-network)

Answer (score 90):

I just did `sudo service docker restart` and it worked after. Definitely worth a shot before jumping in to modify your configurations.

Comment: Need to do this every time I suspended/woke up my laptop, to get dns resolution inside docker back to work.

Comment: A good advice indeed. Before fiddling with config, try the basics. Also going inside the container with an interactive session is always a nice way to understand what's wrong _before_ applying a solution.    

`docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/sh name-of-your-image-here`

Comment: This solved my issue. In my case, expressvpn would connect on system startup, and then I would disconnect later if something was not working. This seemed to mess up docker. Restarting the service like you suggested fixed it.

Answer (score 37):

I got the same problem with Ubuntu 16.04 and Docker version 17.09.0-ce.
I don't think disabling `dnsmasq` is the right solution.

Here is how I solved it:

**For Ubuntu**

Edit /etc/default/docker and add your DNS server to the following line:

Example

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 10.252.252.252"
```

Reference:
[Network calls fail during image build on corporate network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151129/docker-network-calls-fail-during-image-build-on-corporate-network)

Comment: I found the instructions here:  https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#specify-dns-servers-for-docker

Comment: This works for me whilst editing the /etc/docker/daemon.json did not

Comment: This works for me on WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04 where I had the same problem the original poster had (with different python version).

Answer (score 31):

bkasap's answer changes a system's feature I would say is exaggerated. Further because there are options in docker to do that. The new way to do that is

```
$ sudo vi /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

and add following content and modify it if necessary with your dns setup.

```json
{
    "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"]
}
```

Don't forget to

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Comment: your response broked my docker lol

Comment: Are you sure you pasted a valid JSON? What was broken?

Answer (score 24):

It's silly, but I had a VPN connected when I got this error.

After disconnecting the VPN, PIP started working again.

Comment: Came here and nothing was working. Turns out this was my issue as well.

Comment: Thanks i was going crazy haha!

Comment: Lol! this happened with me as well! Any idea why being on a DNS would cause this resolution error ?

Comment: I had the same problem. I'd like to know why having DNS connected at host prevents a container from resolving the name of other container on the same docker network, in a single host compose run.

Comment: This answer is underrated because this fixed the error for me as well.

Answer (score 17):

On fedora 32 it was problem with firewall. Following command resolved issue:

```
$firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-interface=docker0

$firewall-cmd --reload
```

Answer (score 16):

this post worked for me too!

> Solved by dns mask *[sic]* disable:
>
> sudo vim /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
>
> comment out dns=dnsmasq -> #dns=dnsmasq
>
> sudo service network-manager restart (or reboot VM in this case)

from: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26330

Comment: Why is everybody willingly calling masquerading masking (not just this answer)? The difference matters - especially for understanding. We don't want to just mash keys until "it works". We need to understand what works, and why. (I realize this was a quote, but just search this SO post for `mask` to see my point)

Answer (score 14):

Had this just now, on my Ubuntu 20.04. Randomly, it just stopped working!

Tried:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Did not work. Then I just did:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

and the issue was resolved!

Comment: Had similar problem over here. `sudo systemctl restart docker` was enough for solving the issue. Thank you

Comment: In my case I had to restart the machine. As I had docker installed via snap before that.

Answer (score 8):

This error means your Docker container is unable to access your network. 
Beginning with systemd version 220, the forwarding setting for a given network (net.ipv4.conf..forwarding) defaults to off. This setting prevents IP forwarding. It also conflicts with Docker’s behavior of enabling the net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding setting within containers.

If your container needs to resolve hosts which are internal to your network, the public nameservers will not be adequate. You have two choices:

1. You can specify a DNS server for Docker to use, or
2. You can disable dnsmasq in NetworkManager. If you do this, NetworkManager will add your true DNS nameserver to /etc/resolv.conf, but you will lose the possible benefits of dnsmasq.
   You only need to use one of these methods.

you can read about how to perform these steps [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/linux-postinstall/#dns-resolver-found-in-resolvconf-and-containers-cant-use-it)

Answer (score 5):

I am having the same issue with Ubuntu 16.04.1 machine for docker-ce 17. 
Its got fixed by disable the dns mask in the network.

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Press **Ctrl+O** save and **Enter** the exit **Ctrl+X**

Restart the network service by running bellow command.

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

After this if you run the docker build command everything will work fine.

Comment: This worked for me, whereas adding the correct DNS servers did not.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem on Windows 10 Pro and I solved it by right clicking on the docker icon in the tray and choosing "Restart...".  It took a few mins and then the network was running fine again.

Answer (score 2):

for me rebooting host machine resolved the issue

Answer (score 2):

### Docker build: "Temporary failure in name resolution"

I also got the "temporary failure in name resolution" too. My solution was to specify the network on the docker build command:

```
s001# docker network create example_net
s001# docker build --network example_net -t example_image example_image
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I also configured the dns on docker config on my development notebook:

```
s001# nano /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "dns": ["8.8.8.8"]
}
s001# systemctl restart docker
```

Answer (score 2):

Thats the solution that worked for me:

https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-build-fails-on-pip-install-from-temporary-failure-in-name-resolution/87227

Just executed `docker network list` and tested with the differents networks on the `docker build --network=XXX .`. The one that worked was `host`.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the default DNS server in `/etc/resolv.conf` and it worked for me.

FROM:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
```

TO:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8 
#nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
```

I just added the DNS server of Google and commented out the default DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

My case was tricky and related to environmental conditions, but is worth mentioning.
I was under a firewall with bandwidth limitations based on its own hierarchy-based logic (critical, hard, medium traffic, etc...).

Every time I was starting huge docker pull, everything on my host started misbehaving (https browser navigation based upon DNS, ping based upon DNS, ... and Docker, ofc.

Removing those limits fixed my problem, so check your network, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing it on windows machine,you can configure the way docker containers interact with network and set dns manually.
Settings=>Resources=>Network=>Manual DNS Configuration
[Here is how it is configured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWNKf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to check your internet connection especially if you are using a virtual machine in cloud (for example EC2).

I had no internet connection when I tried to run a container in the EC2. I was connected by bastion host to the VM. I didn't have internet connection for the virtual machine.

I wasted too much time. I hope this answer helps the people like me.

Answer (score 0):

I was using "Cisco AnyConnect" as a VPN client on Ubuntu. It was disconnecting every time a URL had to be resolved.

I ended up using another VPN client.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I disabled `iptables` in the `daemon.json`. Removing that helped me to get my image build.