# pip can not install requirements after docker-compose up

Tags: python, django, docker, requirements.txt

i got these errors and warnings after step 6 of sudo docker-compose up

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/asn1crypto/
>
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/asn1crypto/
>
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/asn1crypto/
>
> ‌ WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/asn1crypto/
>
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/asn1crypto/
>
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement asn1crypto==0.24.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for asn1crypto==0.24.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))

this is my Dockerfile codes:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /todo_service
WORKDIR /todo_service
COPY /requirements.txt /todo_service
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /todo_service/
```

what should i do to up it without any warning and err?

Comment: It seems to be a connection issue. Read out here https://development.robinwinslow.uk/2016/06/23/fix-docker-networking-dns/

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44761246/temporary-failure-in-name-resolution-errno-3-with-docker

Answer (score 0):

Docker container seems to have a problem connecting or resolving the URLs. Go to `/etc/default/docker` (In Ubuntu Desktop package installed docker) and uncomment the following line.

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4"
```