# Pip hangs on Starting new HTTPS connection

Tags: python, docker, pip

I'm running docker in docker instance on which I'm trying to build docker image. However during the build everything hangs on `pipe install` command. My base image is nvidia/cuda:10.1-base-ubuntu16.04.

Here is command I'm trying to run in my Dockerfile

```
  python -m pip --no-cache-dir --default-timeout=1000 install -U jupyter \
  jupyter_contrib_nbextensions \
  jupytext -vvv &&\
```

Here are detailed logs

```
Collecting jupyter
  1 location(s) to search for versions of jupyter:
  * https://pypi.org/simple/jupyter/
  Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/jupyter/
  Found index url https://pypi.org/simple
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org:443
  https://pypi.org:443 "GET /simple/jupyter/ HTTP/1.1" 200 496
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.org/simple/jupyter/
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/83/df/0f5dd132200728a86190397e1ea87cd76244e42d39ec5e88efd25b2abd7e/jupyter-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=5b290f93b98ffbc21c0c7e749f054b3267782166d72fa5e3ed1ed4eaf34a2b78 (from https://pypi.org/simple/jupyter/), version: 1.0.0
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c9/a9/371d0b8fe37dd231cf4b2cff0a9f0f25e98f3a73c3771742444be27f2944/jupyter-1.0.0.tar.gz#sha256=d9dc4b3318f310e34c82951ea5d6683f67bed7def4b259fafbfe4f1beb1d8e5f (from https://pypi.org/simple/jupyter/), version: 1.0.0
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/21/a372b73e3a498b41b92ed915ada7de2ad5e16631546329c03e484c3bf4e9/jupyter-1.0.0.zip#sha256=3e1f86076bbb7c8c207829390305a2b1fe836d471ed54be66a3b8c41e7f46cc7 (from https://pypi.org/simple/jupyter/), version: 1.0.0
  Given no hashes to check 3 links for project 'jupyter': discarding no candidates
  Using version 1.0.0 (newest of versions: 1.0.0)
  Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-unpack-i95zt6ip
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): files.pythonhosted.org:443
```

And also logs from other runs

```
Collecting jupyter
  1 location(s) to search for versions of jupyter:
  * https://pypi.org/simple/jupyter/
  Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/jupyter/
  Found index url https://pypi.org/simple
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org:443
```

As you can see, it hangs on `Starting new HTTPS connection (1):` and sometimes it passes the first one but fails on second one.

I added `--no-cache-dir` and `--default-timeout=1000` basing on other answers but it didn't help me. My `pip install` worked once but it was before I had `-vvv` option so don't know how it could complete, however my Dockerfile contains three `pip install` commands and later it failed on second one.

Big problem is that I'm not able to get the configuration of the machine that builds that docker image, when I tried it locally then everything was OK. I doesn't really matter if it's one `pip install` or many.

So, my question is: what could be a reason of pip hanging in that exact moment?

Comment: which base image you use ?

Comment: @LinPy I'm using nvidia/cuda:10.1-base-ubuntu16.04

Comment: I suggest you to try updating pip first

Comment: @LinPy thanks, however it did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not figure how to use `pip install` in that environment, however I found a workaround.

There was a need to install anaconda(miniconda3) on that docker image and instead of using `pip install` I started using `conda install` for package management inside. It seems that `conda` did not have any problems so it was definetly a `pip` issue.

Answer (score 17):

Disabling IPv6 support on my machine solved it for me.
Works for ubuntu 20.04
Open the config file for setting system variables

```
sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Add the following lines to the end

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1 
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Load the settings

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

Verify the settings by viewing the disable_ipv6 flag. This should display **1** if it shows **0** one of the above steps failed

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

Source: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5469#issuecomment-393919476

Comment: encountered on letbox: ipv6 was enabled but no public address was attached to it. disabling ipv6 altogether solved the issue indeed

Comment: Instead, I set up an ipv6 address, can ping with no firewall, but no website access yet, so i fallback to disabling ipv6. :( ```ping ipv6.google.com
PING ipv6.google.com(ams15s48-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:400e:811::200e)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from ams15s48-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:400e:811::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=121 time=3.84 ms
```

Comment: Aaaah now it works fine. Great insight! First time in IPv6... Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.1-base-ubuntu16.04

RUN apt-get update &&  apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN python3 -m pip --no-cache-dir --default-timeout=1000 install -U jupyter \
  jupyter_contrib_nbextensions \
  jupytext -vvv \
```

please note that will install `python3.5` , that should work since `jupyter` works up from `python3.3`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to reply. It didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Same as before, it hangs on pip. I will try to fix it in different way and will post if I find anything, thanks so help.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to being on a company network or VPN. Se this related question: [Temporary failure in name resolution [Errno -3] with Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44761246/temporary-failure-in-name-resolution-errno-3-with-docker)