# RUN curl fails in dockerfile but works from command line

Tags: docker, curl

Using Ubuntu 16.04 and docker 18.03.1-ce

In a Dockerfile I have:

```
RUN curl -k -o app.jar -kfSL https://mynexus:9006/repository/legacy/1.0.2/app.jar
```

But when I build that with:

```
sudo docker build -t myimage .
```

I get:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: mynexus
The command '/bin/sh -c curl -k -o app.jar -kfSL https://mynexus:9006/repository/legacy/1.0.2/app.jar' returned a non-zero code: 6
```

If I run the exact same command line from a terminal it works fine:

```
$ curl -k -o app.jar -kfSL https://mynexus:9006/repository/legacy/1.0.2/app.jar
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 3613k  100 3613k    0     0  1413k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 1413k
```

Why can I curl that file from command line but not from the DockerFile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Name resolution failing during docker build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786057/name-resolution-failing-during-docker-build)

Answer (score 1):

You can see the curl error message when running the last commited image from the build with curl command:

```
docker run -it --rm lastCommitedImageHash curl -k -o app.jar -kfSL https://mynexus:9006/repository/legacy/1.0.2/app.jar
```

I had the same problem last week - curl worked directly from host but not when ran during build from Dockerfile.

Restart of Docker daemon helped to me.

I haven't found what was the reason of that state. It was on the machine which is also as a Kubernetes master and I did Kubernetes cluster upgrade last week and probably this was the source of that problem.

Another cause of that problem in your case can be if you have *mynexus* hostname defined only in the */etc/hosts* file on the host machine and then it is unknown for the running container during the build.

Comment: Aha if I specify the IP address it works. I have tried to restart docker daemon multiple times but that did not help. mynexus is not in the /etc/hosts file

Comment: Then you can look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151129/docker-network-calls-fail-during-image-build-on-corporate-network
And add {"dns": ["yourDnsServerIp"] } into the /etc/docker/daemon.json file and restart docker daemon to apply changes.

Comment: Running curl with `-fL` fixed it for me.