# Inside docker got error as fatal: unable to access <url> Could not resolve host: github.com

Tags: linux, git, docker

I have set up a docker container.The container i got from  dockerhub and installed it using

docker pull gilbitron/php5.6-mysql

I ran the container but i cant clone from git

```
 root@b5ff858016a9:/var/www/html# git clone https://github.com/person/project.git
    Cloning into 'bloodbank'...
    fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/person/project.git': Could not resolve host: github.com
```

Answer (score 0):

That means the DNS is not working from within your container.

Try, as in "[Network calls fail during image build on corporate network](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51756126/6309)", to add the [dns network setting](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings) to your `docker run` command

```
 docker run --dns 10.0.0.2 <image_name> bash
```

Replace "`10.0.0.2`" by your DNS IP (`ipconfig --all` or [`ipconfig /a` on PC](https://askleo.com/find-dns-server-used-pc/).

Comment: CentOS 8 : i had to try changing daemon.json multiple times, as in other links, 8.8.8.8 wasn't working for me as default DNS, the IP from cat /etc/resolv.conf worked - also needed to add rule to firewalld and forgot to restart it afterwards - don't know if that was the culprit.

Comment: and once more, the useful link : https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/