# unable to clone a repo inside a docker container

Tags: git, docker, github, networking, alpine-linux

I was creating my own development env with docker
this is my docker file

```
FROM alpine:latest
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade
RUN reboot
RUN apk add --no-cache make
RUN apk add 
RUN git config --global user.name "username"
RUN git config --global user.email "email"
RUN git config --global init.defaultBranch main
RUN export GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM=1
RUN reboot
```

and one more thing in my original file I have given proper username and email for the git config

now I created image out of this Dockerfile with

```
docker build -t xyz .
```

created a container using

```
docker run --rm -it -v %cd%:/app xyz sh
```

but the problem comes when I try to clone a directory

```
git clone https://github.com/coder/code-server.git
```

the error I get

```
Cloning into 'code-server'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/coder/code-server.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com
```

is this problem from the docker networking part (do I have to define DNS manually ..?)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6oOW.png)
and my internet is working perfectly and I can ping google.com but not github.com
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmZWP.png)

the things I have tried to solve this problem

git config --global --unset https.proxy  (used this) (didn't work)
git config --global --unset http.proxy  (used this) (didn't work)
tried to use ssh still didn't work (using openssh-client) (i installed openssh-client on the alpine)
and I more thing
I have tried to clone the repo on other folders also (other than the mounted folder /app)

I was expecting that the container can reach the github.com

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Network calls fail during image build on corporate network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151129/network-calls-fail-during-image-build-on-corporate-network)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure this is a DNS issue, so try, as mentionned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62382173/22119186), to run your docker image with a dns ip configured :

`docker run --rm -it --dns 10.0.0.2  -v %cd%:/app xyz sh`

Be careful to add **--dns 10.0.0.2**

Replace "10.0.0.2" by your DNS IP (ipconfig --all or ipconfig /a)

Comment: You might flag this question as a duplicate of [Inside docker got error as fatal: unable to access <url> Could not resolve host: github.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62376346/inside-docker-got-error-as-fatal-unable-to-access-url-could-not-resolve-host) rather than repeating its answer.  That in turn cites [Network calls fail during image build on corporate network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151129/network-calls-fail-during-image-build-on-corporate-network) and possibly that is an even better duplicate target.

Comment: Yes i haven't thought about doing so, I will be more carefull in the future, my bad !

Comment: yea it's now working like a charm thank you @bschaffh . one more thing I think the best dns to use 8.8.8.8 or 0.0.0.0 instead of your computers dns ip thank you again